# Ionic 2 - How to remove split panel on login page only?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I use this code in app.html, the split-pane is working beautifully. But the problem is, the pane is working for every page like login or SignUp, so please help me to prevent the split pane working for every page.

```
<ion-split-pane when="(min-width: 768px)">
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-content id="Chat">
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content></ion-nav>
</ion-split-pane>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what *hoeksms* mentioned [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/disable-splitpane-on-specific-page/84107/5), you could use a shared service like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class SplitPaneData {

    splitPaneState: boolean;

    constructor(public platform: Platform) {
        this.splitPaneState = false;
    }

    setSplitPane(state: boolean) {
        if (this.platform.width() > 768) {
            this.splitPaneState = state;
        } else {
            this.splitPaneState = false;
        }
    }

    getSplitPane() {
        return this.splitPaneState;
    }

}
```

And in the app.component use that service to show/hide it:

```
<ion-split-pane [when]="splitPaneData.getSplitPane()">
```

If you want to hide it in a given page, you can use the `ionViewWillEnter` and `ionViewWillLeave` lifecycle events:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    // Disable the split plane in this page
    this.splitPaneData.setSplitPane(false);
}

ionViewWillLeave() {
    // Enable it again when leaving the page
    this.splitPaneData.setSplitPane(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sebaferreras, it's working, but now I want to Disable swipe to view split pane menu..what to do now???

Answer (score 6):

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { MenuController,IonicPage, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

    @IonicPage()

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-signup',
      templateUrl: 'signup.html',
    })

    export class SignUp {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public menu : MenuController) 
    {   
       this.menu.enable(false);
       this.menu.swipeEnable(false);
    }

    ionViewWillLeave(){
    this.menu.enable(true);
    this.menu.swipeEnable(true);
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps. just disable menu and swipe the menu with that splitpane automatically hides.

Comment: Using the MenuController is the best way, but should move disable methods (menu.enable(false) and menu.swipeEnable(false)) from constructor to ionViewWillEnter event.

Answer (score 1):

**update ionic 5**

work for me login.page.ts

```
  constructor(
    private api: LoginService,
    private loadCt: LoadingController,
    private nav : NavController,
    public menu : MenuController
    ) {
      this.menu.enable(false);
      this.menu.swipeGesture(false)
     }

     ionViewWillLeave(){
      this.menu.enable(true);
      this.menu.swipeGesture(true);
      }
```